# Outputting ANSI GIF In Java

Tags: java, terminal

So, I have this code that is meant to take a given .gif file and turn each frame into ANSI chars and then output it (to the PuTTy terminal) with the correct colors. My issue is, It's very blocky. I have been trying to fix this for around 2 hours and cannot get around it, I have provided the code & picture of the issue

Code:

```
public static void displayImage(BufferedImage image, BufferedWriter out) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int consoleWidth = 80;
        int consoleHeight = 24;
        double imageWidth = image.getWidth();
        double imageHeight = image.getHeight();
        double aspectRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;
        int scaledWidth = consoleWidth;
        int scaledHeight = (int) (consoleWidth / aspectRatio);
        if (scaledHeight > consoleHeight) {
            scaledHeight = consoleHeight;
            scaledWidth = (int) (consoleHeight * aspectRatio);
        }
        BufferedImage scaledImage = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = scaledImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null);
        g.dispose();
        out.write(String.format("\033[31m\033[47m"));
        out.write(String.format("\033[2J"));
        out.write(String.format("\033[1;1H"));
        out.write(String.format("\033[?25l"));
        out.write(String.format("\033[0m"));
        out.write(String.format("\033[%dA", consoleHeight));
        for (int y = 0; y < consoleHeight; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < consoleWidth; x++) {
                int sx = x * scaledWidth / consoleWidth;
                int sy = y * scaledHeight / consoleHeight;
                int color = scaledImage.getRGB(sx, sy);
                int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xff;
                int red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
                int green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
                int blue = color & 0xff;
                // convert RGB to 256-color ANSI code
                int ansiCode = rgbToAnsi(red, green, blue);
                // print the ASCII character with foreground and background colors
                out.write(String.format("\u001b[48;5;%dm\u001b[38;5;%dm ", ansiCode, ansiCode));
            }
            out.write("\u001b[0m\r\n"); // reset colors
        }
        out.write(String.format("\033[%dA", consoleHeight));
        out.write(String.format("\033[?25h"));
        out.flush();
        Thread.sleep(250);
    }

    private static int rgbToAnsi(int red, int green, int blue) {
        // convert RGB to 256-color ANSI code
        int gray = (int) (0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue);
        if (gray < 8) {
            return 16;
        }
        if (gray > 248) {
            return 231;
        }
        int r = getClosestColorValue(red);
        int g = getClosestColorValue(green);
        int b = getClosestColorValue(blue);
        return 16 + 36 * r + 6 * g + b;
    }

    private static int getClosestColorValue(int value) {
        return Math.round(value / 51.0f);
    }
```

Issue:
[Blocky Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YF7ru.png)
[Blocky Image #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drD3l.png)

The Gif I'm trying to use:
https://tenor.com/view/explosion-fate-anime-gif-26130203

Comment: Yes, it's blocky, what is the actual problem?

Comment: You're not attempting to get that high-res (and animated!) image to appear in the terminal are you??

Comment: @g00se Not exactly looking for exactly high res but I have seen examples of this where it was outputted in a terminal in better quality and way recognizable than that

Comment: @jon-hanson I havee already posted a comment about it but basically I've seen examples of this where it was in way better quality and way recognizable than what mine is, which is strange I suppose

Comment: I think we need a more clear problem statement. The code is doing exactly what I would expect it to do, and it's not clear why you expect it to produce higer resolution images. Your approach is using terminal colour codes, so the resolution will be one colour (i.e. pixel) per character.

Comment: @jon-hanson I'm more looking to see if there's a way to make the image more recognizable as I've seen in other programs I've used

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](https://manytools.org/hacker-tools/convert-image-to-ansi-art/go/) site, I get the following in my terminal from your source image:

[image]

I post this, not as an answer, but more as a realistic assessment of what might be achieved.